# Consistent width of boxplots if missing data by group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a similar question previously discussed for **barplots**, but with missing solution for **boxplots**: [Consistent width for geom_bar in the event of missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020437/consistent-width-for-geom-bar-in-the-event-of-missing-data)

I would like to produce a **boxplots by groups**. However, **data for some groups can be missing, leading to increased width of boxplots with missing groups**.

I tried to specify `geom_boxplot(width = value`) or `geom_boxplot(varwidth = F)`, but this does not work.

Also, as suggested for barplots example, I tried to add `NA` values for missing data group. Boxplot just only skipp missing data, and extent the boxplot width. I got back the warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

---

Dummy example:

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a data frame
variety=rep(LETTERS[1:7], each=40)
treatment=rep(c("high","low"),each=20)
note=seq(1:280)+sample(1:150, 280, replace=T)

# put data together
data=data.frame(variety, treatment ,  note)

ggplot(data, aes(x=variety, y=note, fill=treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

**Boxplots have the same width if there are values for each group:**

[image: boxplots have the same width is there are values for each group]

Remove the values for 1 group:

```
# subset the data to have a missing data for group:
data.sub<-subset(data, treatment != "high" | variety != "E" )

windows(4,3)
ggplot(data.sub, aes(x=variety, y=note, fill=treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

**Boxplot with missing data is wider than another ones:**

[image]

---

**Is there a way how to keep constant width of boxplots?**

Answer (score 42, accepted):

We can make use of the `preserve` argument in `position_dodge` / `position_dodge2`.

From `?position_dodge`

> preserve: Should dodging preserve the total width of all elements at a position, or the width of a single element?

```
p <- ggplot(data.sub, aes(x=variety, y=note, fill=treatment))

# position_dodge
p + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

```
# position_dodge2
p + 
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

Comment: Improvement but not entirely satisfying since empty space should be on the left in this case

Comment: Thanks @sindri_baldur for the heads up. Added the position_dodge2 option